# Counting frequency

Tags: r

So i have an excel file with the format:

```
StudID      Score

2234          96
1056          20
9886          70
6542          65
4315          15
2234          40
6542          97
9886          56
4315          32
6542          54
```

and I'm trying to obtain the frequency of each occurrence of StudID. Where i would **obtain**:

```
StudID        Frequency

2234              2
1056              1
9886              2
4315              2
6542              3
```

Additionally, based on the above i would like to get the StudID with the **largest frequency** hence in this case it would be **StudID 6542**.

```
stud <- read.csv("student.csv")
freq <- table(stud$StudID)
colnames(freq) <- c("StudID", "Frequency")
freq[which.max(freq)]
```

but it seemed like I'm getting an error message saying:

> Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("StudID", "Frequency")) : attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions

Comment: The error is telling you that `colnames` will not work on a table i.e. an object with less than two dimensions. FYI, `6542` only appears twice in your example, not 3 times

Comment: @Sotos my mistake, edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that yu are trying to assign `colnames` to an object with less than 2 dimensions. Indeed If we inspect the structure of `table()`, then we can see that it is a 1-dimensional object, i.e.

```
str(table(df$V1))
 'table' int [1:5**(1d)**] 1 2 2 2 2 #(1d = 1 dimension)
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  ..$ : chr [1:5] "1056" "2234" "4315" "6542" ...
```

What you want to do is convert to a data frame first and then assign names, i.e.

```
dd <- setNames(as.data.frame(table(df$V1)), c('StudID', 'Freq'))

#  StudID Freq
#1   1056    1
#2   2234    2
#3   4315    2
#4   6542    3
#5   9886    2
```

To extract the maximum, you can just do,

```
dd$StudID[which.max(dd$Freq)]
#[1] 6542
#Levels: 1056 2234 4315 6542 9886
```

**DATA:**

```
dput(df)
structure(list(V1 = c(2234L, 1056L, 9886L, 4315L, 2234L, 6542L, 
9886L, 4315L, 6542L, 6542L), V2 = c(96L, 20L, 70L, 15L, 40L, 
97L, 56L, 32L, 54L, 13L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

**EDIT:**
To have it not return Levels as per your comment, we can simply convert to character, i.e.

```
dd$StudID <- as.character(dd$StudID)
dd$StudID[which.max(dd$Freq)]
#[1] 6542
```

Comment: is it possible to just return "6542" instead of together with the Levels?

Comment: @Maxxx Of course. It has levels because it is a factor so just convert to character. See my edit

Answer (score 2):

In base R, we could use `aggregate` and then follow your `which.max` logic

```
freq <- aggregate(Score~StudID, df, length)
freq[which.max(freq$Score), ]

#  StudID Score
#4   6542     3
```

Or if you want only the `ID`

```
freq$StudID[which.max(freq$Score)]
#[1] 6542
```

---

Or with `table`

```
names(which.max(table(df$StudID)))
#[1] "6542"
```